# PHP SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, svn, laravel

I'm working on a project (PHP Laravel 4.2) using SVN with team, After I checked out the repository on my disk (local), and tried to open the link `localhost/mylaravel`, I got this error

> PDOException (1045)  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'dbusername'@'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' (using password: YES)

Note: I changed the real username and host IP

the database not locally, It's remotely hosted online. but the project is on localhost.

config/database.php

```
'connections' => array(

        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

        /**
         * remote database connection
         */
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'hostIP:port',
            'database'  => 'mydatabasename',
            'username'  => 'mydbusername',
            'password'  => 'root123456',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'forge',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),

        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

    )
```

Comment: Does the database has permission for remote access?

Comment: No, more than member of the team works on the same database @NathanvanderWerf

Comment: I'd have thought the error was fairly clear. You are trying to access a database server but you have an incorrect username and/or password.

Comment: I thought I need additional configurations that I should do because I'm using localhost @halfer

Comment: Quite possibly. If you have a local database, you can edit this file with your local database credentials (we obviously can't tell you what those credentials are - you need to set them up). Additionally you may wish to add in an environment system that detects whether you are running locally or on a remote server, and connects to the correct one automatically.

Comment: I tried to connect to localhost and it's connect successfully which means the problem with credentials or permissions for my username, I'll contact the database provider, by the way thank you for your help @NathanvanderWerf

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same problem. I can connect locally, but I can't do it with a remote one. The weird thing is that I'm able to do it by using MySQL Workbench. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following artisan commands in your terminal.
1. `php artisan cache:clear`
2. `php artisan config:cache`

Refresh your url now and the login will works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!
$ php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
```

Run php artisan cache:clear then php artisan config:cache on your terminal in the respective path.

The above should be the results

Answer (score 0):

I Faced Same Problem i did

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:cache

but Same problem found than i run this artisan command

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Hope it will helpful.
Note: my project was Laravel 5.*

Answer (score 0):

Just only change `.env` file and DON'T change `config/database.php` file. Please make `config/database.php` file as default.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 or IP address
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE='your database name'
DB_USERNAME='your username'
DB_PASSWORD='your password'
```

**it works for me!**

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command line:

```
php artisan optimize
```